# Eigenvalues of a matrix with special form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $p,a_1,...,a_n\in(0,1)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^na_i=1$. Now consider the following matrix:

$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
(1-p) & \sqrt{p(1-p)}a_1 & \sqrt{p(1-p)}a_2 & ... & \sqrt{p(1-p)}a_n\\
\sqrt{p(1-p)}a_1 & pa_1 & 0 & ... & 0\\
\sqrt{p(1-p)}a_2 & 0 & pa_2 & ... & 0\\
... & 0 & 0 & ... & 0\\
\sqrt{p(1-p)}a_n & 0 & 0 & ... & pa_n\\
 \end{array}\right) 
$$

Some simple properties are that its rank is $n-1$ and for $a_i=1$ it has a single eigenvalue which equals 1. What I would like to know is a closed form for its eigenvalues. Does anybody see an easy way of computing the eigenvalues of this matrix?

Comment: The dependence on $p$ can be eliminated by a suitable similarity transformation (can you spot it?). This reduces the problem down to the case of $p=1/2$.

Comment: @Semiclassical I certainliy cannot spot the transformation. Could you explain?